# Compounded returns over $n$ days

Tags: equities

I have calculated the daily returns of a certain stock. They can be analytically described by a 3 parameter Student's $t$ distribution whose [density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Probability_density_function) is

$$f(x)=\frac{\left(\frac{\nu}{\nu+\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\right)^{\frac{\nu+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{\nu}\sigma B\left(\frac\nu2,\frac12\right)},$$
where $\mu=0.11$, $\sigma=0.54$ and $\nu=1.52$.

With this starting point: how can I calculate the distribution function of (compounded) returns over $n$ days?

Comment: As far as I remember, there exists no 'nice' closed form density or even characteristic function for the student distribution. There exists no 'simple' way to extend the 1day-case to an N-day case under the t-distribution, to my knowledge.

Comment: and how about a more 'well behaved' gaussian distribution? or in general, without specifying the distribution line shape?

Comment: @Luigi You can simply add normally distributed log-returns using the [convolution stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) of that distribution, i.e. that sum is still normal. The sum of Student $t$ distribution is not Student $t$ though, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10856/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-difference-of-two-t-distributions).

Comment: @Kevin, so I should calculate the log-returns for 1 day and then add them n times to get the compounded returns for n days?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Kevin's very helpful comment + link, if you need to calculate the distribution / density of the sum of (any) independent continuous random variables, e.g. sum of Student *t* distributed vars, or some other mixture, you can go two ways:

### Option A: Simulation

Simply simulate the target distribution $N$ number of times. You can then estimate moments, quantiles etc. from that.

**N.B:** Make sure that $N$ is sufficiently large, e.g. through resampling and testing the tightness of your estimators. For distributions whose moments are not defined, (e.g. with $d.o.f.\leq 4$ for a Student *t* distribution, if you require first four moments) you might need lots of simulations to get sufficient results.

### Option B: Numerical integration of characteristic functions

We know that the characterstic function of a random variable,

$$
\varphi_X(t)\equiv \int f(x)e^{itx}\mathrm{d}x
$$

[exists always](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197987/why-does-the-characteristic-function-always-exist), and that the characteristic function of the sum of independent random variables is the [product of their individual characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties). Finally, thru [Gil-Pelaez](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373919/general-fourier-inversion-formula-gil-pelaez) or the inversion relationship,

$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-itx}\phi_X(t)\mathrm{d}t,
$$

or more exactly through a **numerical approximation** of this inversion, we can always try to recover the distribution or density of our convoluted variable.

**N.B.:** The numerical inversion can become quite cumbersome if your distribution is not sufficiently *smooth*, e.g. if it is has a strong 'bend' somewhere, implying that you need a very large region of integration to accumulate all material frequency contributions.

HTH?